# Using subquery with two tables

Tags: mysql, sql, subquery

I have 2 tables: `emp` and `dept` which holds information about employees and their departments. I have tried to use subquery to find employees with the same deparment (1, 2, 3 or 4) and check if they have the same job (Clerk, Salesman etc..)

```
SELECT
  e1.ename,
  e1.job
FROM emp e1,
     emp e2
WHERE e2.deptno = 3
AND e1.deptno = 1 IN (SELECT
  deptno
FROM emp
WHERE e1.job = e2.job);
```

This works for finding emp which have the same job in deptno 1 and 3, but when I am trying to find emp which does not have the same job I don't get the right answer.

```
SELECT
  e1.ename,
  e1.job
FROM emp e1,
     emp e2
WHERE e2.deptno = 3
AND e1.deptno = 1 NOT IN (SELECT
  deptno
FROM emp
WHERE e1.job = e2.job);
```

This is actually driving me mental, and I am not why its not working. I need to find a way using sub-query.
Any help is would be amazing!

Comment: Edit your question and provide sample data and desired results.

Comment: not the same job but the same department?

Comment: Instead of a sub-query, why not use a join? If you show your table schema, and some sample data from the two tables, you might get a usable answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Emp doesn't appear to be used in your second query in the subquery:

```
select e1.ename, e1.job 
from emp e1 LEFT OUTER JOIN emp e2 ON e2.deptno = 3 AND E1.JOB=E2.JOB
where e1.deptno = 1 and E2.ENAME IS NULL
```

This should give you the employees not in the same job.

Basically, we join on matching job.  The ENAME being null for E2 (assuming this is a NOT NULL field) means no matching record was found.

Comment: Made some changes.  This assumes EMP.ENAME is a non nullable field.